# Не получается отправить с клиента на сервер

Tags: android, клиент-сервер

Добрый день.

Клиент(Андроид) - Сервер (Java)

С помощью сокетов пытаюсь установить соединение с сервером.

Если с эмулятора значение переменной успешно отправляется (сервер принимает), то когда пытаюсь на реальном телефоне повторить - сервер ничего не получает. Просто тишина. Разрешение на интернет стоит, и не только на интернет, и на вайфай и на все прочее.

Сервер:

```
public class Server {

static ServerSocket ss;
static Socket s;
static DataInputStream dis;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Server get started:\n");
            try{
                ss = new ServerSocket(80);
                while(true){
                    s = ss.accept();
                    dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    System.out.println("Received: " + dis.readUTF());
                    dis.close();
                    s.close();
                }
            } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }

    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Клиент:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

Button btn_start;
TextView welcome_text_view;
public static String name = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText et = new EditText(MainMenu.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    et.setPadding(16, 0, 0, 16);
    et.setLayoutParams(lp);

    AlertDialog.Builder inputNameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this);
    inputNameDialog
            .setTitle("You are welcome!")
            .setMessage("Input your name:")
            .setPositiveButton("Go!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    name = et.getText().toString();
                    if(!name.equals("")) welcome_text_view.setText("Hello, " + name + "!");
                    new Connecter1().execute();
                }
            })
            .setView(et)
            .create();
    inputNameDialog.show();

    welcome_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_text_view);

    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Game.class); 
            startActivity(intent);
            GamePanel.speed = 10;
            GamePanel.score = 0;
        }
    });
}

private class Connecter1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("Мой ip", 80);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(name);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Когда на эмуляторе ставил ip 192.168... локальный, короче - все работало.
Теперь, когда запускаю на реальном устройстве, поменял ip, узнав его на 2ip.
На реальном устройстве данные передаются через wi-fi, если это имеет значение.

Так в чем же тут все-таки проблема?

Comment: А у вас включен wi-fi в телефоне?

Comment: Да, wi-fi включен

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `HttpUrlConnection`, какие сокеты?

Comment: Пример накидать можете? И этот коннект так же надо будет реализовывать в отдельном потоке?